# chroot + mount = EBUSY

Tags: mount, chroot

I have a large, complex application. I'm trying to run it from a boot CD, which is obviously read-only. But the application needs a large writable area. (A ramdisk won't cut it.) So I've managed to construct a chroot environment to make it look to the application as if it's running from a normal writable environment.

The trouble is, one of the first things the application tries to do is mount some devices that are already mounted. I was expecting the kernel to allow that, but it seems if you try to remount a device with *different* mount options, the `mount(2)` call returns `EBUSY`. I need to make that stop happening.

The application has no idea that it's being run in this slightly strange configuration. I don't really want to change the application code to make this work. Is there some way I can instruct the kernel to pretend to mount something read-only even though it's already mounted somewhere else as read-write?

---

OK, so people said the question is unclear. Let's try this again:

```
~# mount /dev/sdb1 /XData
~# mkdir /tmp/CD
~# mount --bind / /tmp/CD
~# mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=/tmp/CD,upperdir=/XData/Root,workdir=/XData/Work none /NewRoot
~# chroot /NewRoot
~# java /home/user7/app.jar
```

Of course, `app.jar` has *no idea* that I'm doing this, so it immediately tries to do

```
mount --ro /dev/sdb1 /XData
```

which fails. What I'm looking for is a way to make it not fail. I don't really want to alter the application JAR file, but I'm totally OK with altering the commands leading up to launching it. Basically I want `app.jar` to think everything is normal and nothing weird is happening. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

(It seems if you try to mount something several times *with the same options*, the kernel is perfectly fine with that. But trying to mount with *different* options seems to upset it.)

Comment: In that environment, can you replace mount by a programme of your own?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That's an interesting suggestion... What are you thinking? Replace it with some kind of script?

Comment: If your application is satisfied with a script, that would be the easiest solution.  (Has to be executable, of course, and start with a shebang).

Comment: This question is simply too fuzzy to be answered sensibly. I'm afraid you have to post more details.

Comment: @countermode How do I make is so that stuff mounted outside chroot can be mounted again inside chroot without errors? Seems like a pretty clear question to me...

Comment: Generic answer: mount it from outside into the chroot. Beyond that, it is of course up to you to post more details or not, but I bet it is _much_ more likely to get a suitable answer if you provide, say, a relevant command line transcript. N.B. there are already several votes to close the question on the ground of being unclear, so "pretty clear" is apparently a matter of view.

Comment: Following in from the first suggestion to replace `mount` with a script, this is the option I would consider first, too. But it really depends on whether the Java program uses the external `mount` program to perform the mount or it uses some form of library call. If it's the latter you'd need to look at schemes that override library calls in a manner such as `fakeroot`.

Comment: @roaima The Java code calls `/usr/bin/mount`, so I could plausibly replace it and make it do something strange... Maybe post that suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work for you. If it doesn't, please let me know the `mount` log messages written to `/var/log/user.log`, `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Mount should be a no-op if called as "mount --ro /dev/sdb1 /XData"
#
# Move the real /usr/bin/mount to /usr/bin/mount.bin, and install this
# script as /usr/bin/mount
########################################################################
#
if [[ "$*" == '--ro /dev/sdb1 /XData' ]]
then
    logger -t mount "NO-OP: $0 $*"
    exit 0
fi

logger -t mount "Action: $0 $*"
exec "$0.bin" "$@"
exit 1
```

Comment: Why not `exit $?` instead of `exit 1`?

Comment: @pixelomer I've used `exit 1` because it makes little sense to return failure codes of `exec` from a script pretending to be `mount`.